# Remove duplicate cordinates from an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

My array contains:-

```
(18.9992561589571, 72.83004879020154),(19.124614516591855, 72.87498710677028)
```

value, But for removing duplicate value i called 'removeDuplicates' function. But some times(In other cordinates it's works fine, But some time it's fails), So i dont know what's wrong with in it. Please help me.

Here is removeDuplicates function:-

```
function removeDuplicates(arr) {
    var n, y, x, i, r;
    r = [];
    o: for (i = 0, n = arr.length; i < n; i++) {
        for (x = 0, y = r.length; x < y; x++) {
            if (r[x][0] == arr[i][0] && r[x][1] == arr[i][1]) {
                continue o;
            }
        }
        r.push(arr[i]);
    }
    return r;
}
```

Input:-

```
array:-   (18.9992561589571, 72.83004879020154),(19.124614516591855, 72.87498710677028)
```

Expected Output:-

```
array:-   (18.9992561589571, 72.83004879020154),(19.124614516591855, 72.87498710677028)
```

Getting:-
`array:-   (18.9992561589571, 72.83004879020154)`

Comment: When asking for help, do people the courtesy of formatting your code and other information in your question clearly. Do **you** think that code is readable? How about the data, clearly presented? There was a preview area under where you were typing the question, an entire toolbar of formatting tools, and a big orange **How to Format** box on the Ask a Question page.

Comment: `(something, something)` is not an array. `[something, something]` is. And your function works quite fine when called [properly](http://jsfiddle.net/LrmW5/).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Removing duplicates from 2d array in Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/519899/removing-duplicates-from-2d-array-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the sake of completeness, here's how I'd implement it:

```
var arr = [[18.9992561589571, 72.83004879020154],
           [19.124614516591855, 72.87498710677028],
           [18.9992561589571, 72.83004879020154]];

function getUniqueTuples(tuples) {
    var a = [], h = {};
    tuples.forEach(function(t) {
        var k = t[0] + '|' + t[1];
        if (!(k in h)) {
            h[k] = null;
            a.push(t);
        }
    });
    return a;
}

arr = getUniqueTuples(arr);
console.log(arr);
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/GWe2A/). The point is replacing array look-up with hash look-up for duplicates - the bigger your array of tuples is, the better will be the speed.

---

Now let's check your code:

```
var a=[];
a.push("(18.9992561589571, 72.83004879020154)");
a.push("(19.124614516591855, 72.87498710677028)");
alert(removeDuplicates(a));
```

Here's the problem: `removeDuplicates` actually is set up to deal with array of *arrays* (which, in turn, should consist of two elements). Yet your original array consists of *strings*, not arrays.

Therefore, `[0]` and `[1]` properties, when compared, are actually 0th and 1st *characters* of those strings - `'('` and `'1'` in both cases, respectively. In other words, your coordinates are considered to be equal if the very first digit in them is the same.

Solution? Either work with arrays from the start, or make arrays from your strings - the easiest way to do it would be using regex, I suppose:

```
var patt = /[\d.]+/g;
var firstCoord = "(18.9992561589571, 72.83004879020154)";
var secondCoord = "(19.124614516591855, 72.87498710677028)"; 
a.push(firstCoord.match(patt), secondCoord.match(patt));
```

Comment: Ya, You are right, Your code is working fine, but whats wrong in my code?   here is demo :-  http://jsfiddle.net/22CuD/   . Because this array contains google map cordinates.

Comment: Updated the answer. Like I said, you've been confused by the type mix.

Comment: May be you are right. But this is my dynamic array so i can apply your pattern thing in my function. For this i modify my code, Please have a look on http://jsfiddle.net/22CuD/1/

Comment: Check the console, and you'll see what's wrong - `for each` is not valid syntax in JS. It's easier to use `$.map` to transform one array (array of strings) into another (array of two-element arrays). Like in [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mLWUk/).

Comment: Now i got it, In this function input and output type must be same, So if we are passing array who has '()' type symbol then output must contain these symbol. i modify my code. You also can check. May be this working fine.  http://jsfiddle.net/22CuD/3/

Comment: Sorry but regular Expression /[\d.]+/g is may be wrong because its not working well with negative value, It remove negative sign. please check here http://jsfiddle.net/22CuD/5/

Comment: Then just add `-` to it, like `/[-\d.]+/g`.